# Curl to AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, curl, paypal, afnetworking

I'm trying to use paypal Express checkout from a native iOS app (can't use paypal SDK because apple needs me to go through safari to make the payment). Problem is when i try to call the SetExpressCheckout API method. Here is the curl statement that they provide at the website:

```
curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d 
"USER=callerID                        # User ID of the PayPal caller account 
&PWD=callerPswd                        # Password of the caller account 
&SIGNATURE=callerSig                   # Signature of the caller account 
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout 
&VERSION=93 
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE     # type of payment 
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19.95              # amount of transaction 
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD       # currency of transaction 
&RETURNURL=http://www.example.com/success.html  # URL of your payment confirmation page 
&CANCELURL=http://www.example.com/cancel.html"  # URL redirect if customer cancels payment
```

I need to pass this to AFNetworking so i can do it inside the app, i've tried this but it's not working:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: kPaypalClientId,@"USER",
     kPaypalPassword, @"PWD",
      kPaypalSignature, @"SIGNATURE",
      @"SetExpressCheckout", @"METHOD",
      @"93", @"VERSION",
       @"SALE",@"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION",
       @"19.95",@"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT",
      @"USD", @"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE",
      @"shareapp://bien",@"RETURNURL",
      @"shareapp://cancel", @"CANCELURL", nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager POST:@"https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" parameters:params
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=%@",tokenValue]]];
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain" UserInfo=0xba7de40 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xd06e720> { URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 230;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    DC = "origin1-api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com";
    Date = "Tue, 15 Apr 2014 13:36:59 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "DC=origin1-api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com; secure";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain}
```

Thank you and sorry for my english!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line solved this for me:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: Correct. The default response serializer is `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. As the PayPal API returns plain text response, you need to use the `AFHTTPRresponseSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the header: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when posting to the Paypal server.

Comment: I used 
    `[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-    urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`
But i still get the same error

Comment: This isn't the reason for the error given in the question